# Vuetify autocomplete - Clear auto complete cache-items list / suggestions

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I clear the cache item list for auto complete ? I am using the cache-items flag. Once The user has the results for the current query and want to try a new list, I need the current items to be cleared.

I have "cache-items" on so the user can see all his selections before submitting.

```
<v-autocomplete v-if="showautocomplete" v-model="autocomplete_model" 
 :items="items" :loading="isLoading" autofocus
:search-input.sync="autocomplete_search" chips clearable hide-selected cache-items>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need this but I think I've found an answer here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11365 from bka9.

You can add a ref on your v-autocomplete and change the cachedItems through the $refs. I'm not sure when you would have to trigger the method but that's all that's missing.

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete ref="autocomplete" cache-items ... />
</template>

<script>
  methods: {
    clearCachedItems() {
      this.$refs.autocomplete.cachedItems = [];
    },
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Not ideal, but this worked for me. Vuetify's "autocomplete" sure works a lot differently than many other autocompletes I have used over the years. Thank you for sharing this answer!